# Scrollable area with checkboxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter bootstrap (and I suck at css). I would like to have a scrollable area with typically 3 columns of checkboxes. There are plenty of checkboxes and the user can select several. I don't want to waste to much screen on the checkboxes, hence the scroll.

I have tried using css3 columns but then it doesn't work in IE and if combined with overflow it overflows horizontally, I only want vertical scroll bar.

I know it's not the optimal solution user friendly wise but, its what the customer wants.

```
 div.cb_scroll {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
  //height: 300px;
  overflow:auto;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Any easy solutions? If not in css, any simple javascript solution?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/ayx4z/1/

basically you

1. set the height smaller than the div containing the checkboxes
2. set the overflow to auto;
3. make the set width of the containing div is either "auto" or greater than the combined width of the inner divs.

Css:

```
.boxes {
    height: 75px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: auto;
}​`​
```

Comment: Well as the number of boxes is unknown I cannot just enter a tag when its time for a new column. (I can if I perform some count and loop stuff). Which I want to avoid if possible. Apart from that your example is exactly what I mean.

Comment: ok so your problem is a bit more complicate. You want to add more columns as you have more check boxes? You will have explain a bit more exactly how this should work.

Comment: Well, I want a specified number of columns regardless of how many checkboxes. This is why me and CSS ain't best pals. Its a pretty simple thing. Typically I want 4 columns of checkboxes on a scrollable area.

Comment: I think you will either have to set items in the columns on the server side, use javascript to set the columns, or something like this http://rickbjarnason.com/creating-multi-column-lists-using-css/ . Also  maybe with your original css you could try something like this "overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;" instead of overflow:auto;